# Execsync producing errors

Tags: node.js, linux, terminal, child-process

I want to compare my 2 files that i generated ,for that I am using execsync

mycode :

```
  try{
      let child = execSync(`diff output.txt answer.txt`);
      console.log(child.toString());
      return res.json({
          message : child.toString()
      })
  }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.json({
          messager : 'err'
      })
  }
```

It throws below error , I have run the command in shell and it works fine ,exec gives me the desired result but right now cannot use that.

```
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:957:15)
     (/server/controllers/v1/user_api.js:224:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [
    null,
    <Buffer 31 63 31  ... 40 more bytes>,
    <Buffer >
  ],
  pid: 22934,
  stdout: <Buffer 20 ... 40 more bytes>,
  stderr: <Buffer >
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question, to be more on point , if you want to see you can also see the previous question which has extra info